# uploading file with single quotes in filename using move_uploaded_file does not work

Tags: php

i am try to upload images into the system using php, its work fine with other files but when the image contains single quotes, the function does not work.The code below i use to upload and resize image using the defined class.
here is my codes.

```
$filename = strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']);
$filename=mysql_real_escape_string($filename);
$filename=stripslashes($filename);
$whitelist = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'); #example of white list
//$backlist = array('php', 'php3', 'php4', 'phtml','exe'); #example of black list
if(@in_array(end(explode('.', $filename)), $whitelist))
{
$direc=$school_index;
If(!file_exists($direc)) {

/* wherever this particular script will be installed, I want to create a subfolder */

/* Step 1. I need to know the absolute path to where I am now, ie where this script is running from...*/
$thisdir = getcwd();

/* Step 2. From this folder, I want to create a subfolder called "myfiles".  Also, I want to try and make this folder world-writable (CHMOD 0777). Tell me if success or failure... */

if(mkdir($thisdir ."/$direc" , 0777))
{
   $msg= "Directory has been created successfully...";
}
else
{
   $msg= "Failed to create directory...";
}

}




$filename = strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']);


$file=strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']);
$path =$direc;
$ext=pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$name=pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    echo "File alredy exists .So name is changed automatically & moved";
    //$path1="$folder/";
    $leng=strlen($name);

    $name=substr($name,$leng);


    $new_name=$name.$_SESSION['candidate_photo_name'].".".$ext;
    $new_name=addslashes($new_name);
    $upload=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $file_upload=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$school_index."/".$new_name);
    if(!$file_upload){
$int=$_SESSION['candidate_id'];
 $serial=$_SESSION['candidate_serial'];
$msg="Sory,we are unable to upload this file due to file name to contain unrequired characters,please try again later!";

$_SESSION["photo_entry_msg"]=$msg;                  

header("location:client.php?page=upload_student_photo&student_id=$int&serial=$serial"); exit;

    }
$filename=mysql_real_escape_string($new_name);
$filename=$school_index."/".$filename;

require"php/image_resize.class.php";
$resize = new ResizeImage($filename);
$resize->resizeTo(100, 100, 'maxHeight');
$resize->saveImage($filename);
//$resize->move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

            // our sql query
            //echo $_POST['st_int'];
                    $sql_update = mysql_query("UPDATE  photo_entry SET photo='{$filename}' where id='{$int}'") or die("".mysql_error());
                    //$sql_select = mysql_query("SELECT teacher_name from  class_teachers where id='{$int}'");

                    // 

                    if(!$sql_update){
                    $int=$int;
                         $msg=strtoUpper('Error occured during uploading signature for '.$name);
                     header("location:client.php?page=view_upload_photo&t_id=$int&e=".urlencode($msg)); exit;

                    }
                    elseif($sql_update){

                    $int=$int;
                         $msg=strtoUpper('Congratulation for uploading photo for '.$_SESSION['cand_name']);
                         $_SESSION["photo_entry_msg"]=$msg;
                     header("location:client.php?page=view_upload_photo"); exit;



                    }
                }
```

Comment: any help please!coz i have tried to escape special but not works. is there any best way to solve this ? the file name sholud be renamed according to the name of a concerned person, and the name might contain these characters.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is to just replace the single quotes in the file name with something else, for example with underlines.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing except I would implement a rule for a-z and 0-9 only and **everything** else can be an underscore. If this will be stored in a DB then store both new and original filenames if the user was to download it back to their PC and doesn't want to lose any special naming they may have done.

Comment: thanks, bt the folder that contain those images must be downloaded later on, and must have the images with the same name as the person concern