# HTTP 500 error while file uploading using uploadify

Tags: php, uploadify

I have been stuck in the uploading part. I am using uploadify script. The normal files are uploaded successfully but when I tired to upload a file name with 's like ***file's.jpg*** then the HTTP 500 error occurs.
My uploadify script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#attachment').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '<?php echo base_url();?>web/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '<?php echo base_url();?>web/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '<?php echo base_url();?>web/uploadify/cancel.png',   
    //'folder'    : '../../uploads/project_files/',
    'folder'    : '/admin_panel_new/assets/plupload/uploads/',
    'auto'      : true,
    'multi'       : true,   
    'hideButton': false,
    'buttonImg' :  "<?php echo base_url()?>images/attachment_image.gif",    
    'width'     : 132,
    'height'    : 25,
    'removeCompleted' : false,
    'onSelect' : function(file) {   
            $('#submitFeedback').val('Please wait while uploading...');
            $('#submitFeedback').attr('disabled','disabled');           
    },
    'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
        if($('#fileList').val()!='')    
            $('#fileList').val($('#fileList').val()+','+response);                      
        else
            $('#fileList').val(response);   
        //alert($('#fileList').val());  

        $('#submitFeedback').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#submitFeedback').val('Post Feedback');              
    },
    'onError' : function(event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) { alert(errorObj.type + ' ' + errorObj.info ); }
  });
});
</script>
```

I have tried many other solutions but is no luck.

My uploadify.php code is:

```
<?php
$targetFolder = $_POST['targetFolder']; // Relative to the root
$unik =$_POST['timestamp'];

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/'.$unik.'_'.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','txt'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        //
        echo $unik.'_'.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type. Upload Failed';
    }
}
?>
```

The upload error images looks like this
[image]

If anyone has solution please help. Thanks.

Comment: No, actually the file just a kb not a bigger size.

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" status code basically means: "please check the logs to find out what happened". Have you tried so? Just guessing can take really long.

Comment: I have checked it but no any error logs found. As this same code is working like charm in localhost but when tried in live no success. :(

Answer (score 0):

If the problem only occurs with filenames using single quotes, the first place I'd look is

```
$_FILES['Filedata']['name']
```

Since you're concatenating an unescaped input string, there's a fair chance that single quote is throwing things off with `move_uploaded_file`. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549686/uploading-file-with-single-quotes-in-filename-using-move-uploaded-file-does-not) demonstrates a similar problem.

I'd probably just remove the single quotes from the filename before storing it. Or try `addslashes`.

```
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/'.$unik.'_'.str_replace("'","",$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but same error is occurring again using your code also. I have tried to upload a file name as base's_camp_mail.txt and this error occurs.

Comment: Do you have access to the server's error log? That's the first place I'd look for 500 errors. Or try replacing the name with a static string, like "test.txt" just to see if you can isolate the issue to the filename.